# Prevent JSON.parse(data) from cutting off zero digit for String floats

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I am trying to use highcharts to make graphs. I currently have a string which I am looking to convert to a JSON array which looks like the following:

```
[{"chart":{"type":"line","renderTo":"chart_0"},"title":{"text":"Daily Sales & Spend"},
"xAxis":{"categories":["08-03-2015","08-04-2015"]},
"yAxis":{"title":{"text":"Dollars"}},
"series":[{"name":"Spend","data":[73.84,73.75]},{"name":"Sales","data":[1020.90,4007.90]}]}]
```

I need the trailing zeros so that 1020.90 stays 1020.90, on conversion the data becomes the following after the first index:

```
{"chart":{"type":"line","renderTo":"chart_0"},
"title":{"text":"Daily Sales & Spend"},
"xAxis":{"categories":["08-03-2015","08-04-2015"]},
"yAxis":{"title":{"text":"Dollars"}},
"series":[{"name":"Spend","data"[73.84,73.75]},{"name":"Sales","data":[1020.9,4009.9]}]}
```

The 1020.90 converts to 1020.9. I think this is a behavior of the float, but is it possible to convert it to 1020.90 [for display purposes]? I need this for displaying the data using highcharts.

Comment: internally, in most programming languages, trailing zero decimal places  won't be represented. For display purposes, you might be able to use something like [toFixed()](http://stackoverflow.com/a/149099/32763)

Comment: As Loopo says, this should help: `1020.9.toFixed(2)` will return `"1020.90"`.

Comment: Please read the "Format Strings" section at this link - http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/labels-and-string-formatting

Comment: Thanks everyone, Mike Brant, I was one that page and missed the demo. This is a good solution and I might implement it over the other. I ended up adding a 01 so it would be 1020.901 and then set tooltip valueDecimals to two decimal places.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Prevent JSON.parse(data) from cutting off zero digit for String floats

This has nothing to do with JSON; this is about how numbers work in JavaScript

> The 1020.90 converts to 1020.9

There is no "conversion" here. They're the same number.

> I need this for displaying the data using highcharts

Then you need to pad the number with trailing zeros when you convert it to a string.

It is impossible to tell a float how many significant digits it has. You can only impose significant digits when you display the float as a string.

Comment: I didn't know it would cut off zeros with conversion. Thanks for your answer.